# Matlab: read csv into array

Tags: arrays, matlab, csv

im new to matlab and coding. I have a csv file with data that goes like:

`3  2   91  83  17`

`3  2   86  84  4`

`3  2   90  83  162`

(there's a total of 7000 rows)

I need a way to read this into an array, can the array be something like `A[I,J,K,L,M]` with `age=I` for example? How would i go about doing this?

Comment: See [`dlmread`](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/ref/dlmread.html).

Comment: Say I created an array like [age, Doa, los, gender, dest]. Would there be a way to get data in the first coloum in age, data in the second coloum into DOA etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
M = csvread(filename);
age = M(:,1); Doa = M(:,2); los = M(:,3); gender = M(:,4); dest = M(:,5);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer it helped a lot. Im running into an error now though, i have my code as:


M = csvread('peterdatnew.csv', 1,0);
M(:,1) = dest; M(:,2) = gen; M(:,3) = age; M(:,4) = year; M(:,5) = dur;


and i get the error:

Undefined function or variable 'dest'.

i tried dest = 0; gen = 0; but that literally set the value to 0. How should i go about resolving this?

Comment: Sorry, was typing it too quickly, just swap lhs and rhs (see corrected answer)

Comment: Great, you're welcome :). Would you mind accepting an answer to mark it closed, see here http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0):

[`dlmread()`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dlmread.html), [`csvread()`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/csvread.html), and [`xlsread()`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xlsread.html) all work well.

Note that the first two (`dlmread` and `csvread`) are for numeric data only, and `xlsread` is limited by what excel can process (which in my experience is capped at somewhere around 1 million rows). `xlsread` can get you text and raw as well.